# Why don't Jedi spaceships have hyperdrive motors while Sith spaceships do?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, jedi, sith

Jedi single-person spaceships don't have hyperdrive motors (as far as I know), but dock with a ring that has a hyperdrive motor. As shown in the first few seconds of [this movie clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kv1jIojQvIg).

[Darth Maul's spaceship can jump to hyperspace without a separate component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi5T2tSUBaI).

[Count Dooku's sailship doesn't need a separate hyperdrive motor because it can jump too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIdb-et-6sM).

**Why would Jedi not use a spaceship with a hyperdrive motor built into it?**

Just seems vulnerable to have to dock and undock with a hyperdrive unit. And if the hyperdrive unit gets stolen or blasted, well, somebody is stranded on an isolated planet.

Edit: I prefer a G-canon answer with citations, but will settle for a lower canon.

Comment: Would you mind not oneboxing your YT links, they're pretty big and make it hard to read your question.

Comment: I'm not much of a star wars expert but i would guess that carrying around a big hyperdrive motor isn't feasable for single-person spaceships. If your ship has higher weight then you need more thrust to propel yourself. This is especially expensive when this single-person spaceship can be used for landing and starting from planets. Also: Why fix something that isn't broken? Your car can't go over water. You would have to buy a ferryticket for that. And why have a spaceship that can go to hyperdrive when you can just use one of these hyperdrive-rings?

Comment: @JonasDralle The X-wing fighter has a hyperdrive. That's how Luke jumps from the Hoth system to Dagobah. It's probably the smallest ship around with a built-in hyperdrive.

Comment: Cars typically gave 4 tires. But there are sopme who have 8, 16 or more. For example heavy transport vehicles. These are vehicles which have a specific task and it is useful for this specific task to have that many tires: I assume X-wing fighters are becomming better at their task when having a hyperdrive while others do not. Sometimes alone the cost of buying the drive can influence weather the type of ship gets one. Spaceships become cheaper when you need less expensive materials for building one. (I do not have any in-movie sources to support this claim)

Comment: G-Canon doesn't exist any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Star Wars Databank, [Jedi Starfighters](http://www.starwars.com/databank/delta-7-jedi-starfighter) are designed to be **as nimble as possible**. That includes not having bulky hyperdrive systems.

> These wedge-shaped one-man starfighters were built for the Jedi Order.
> **The Delta-7’s designers worked with the Jedi to create a starfighter
> for pilots with Force-aided reflexes, stripping down the fighters’
> systems and making their controls as responsive as possible.** With
> skilled pilots such as Anakin Skywalker and Saesee Tiin at the
> controls, Delta-7s were lightning-quick in combat, darting in for
> attack runs and then skipping nimbly away from retaliatory fire.
>
> <sub><sup>[DELTA-7 JEDI STARFIGHTER - StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank/delta-7-jedi-starfighter)</sup></sub>

The [Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Incredible Cross-Sections](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Incredible-Cross-Sections-Publishing/dp/0756611296) factbook also mentions that many Jedi ships are simply too small to safely contain a hyperdrive

[image]

The original Star Wars Databank article on [hyperdrive rings](http://web.archive.org/web/20100203072432/http://starwars.com/databank/technology/hyperspacering/index.html) also mentions power limitations and the need for Jedi fighters to operate independently of larger ships (and presumably covertly) which necessitates the need for a *detachable* hyperdrive system.

> Small space-faring vessels generally do not have the power plant
> yields or necessary spaceframe to support supralight engines.
> Snubfighters equipped with hyperdrives are rare and expensive, and
> small craft tend to rely on larger carrier ships for extended voyages
> into the depths of space.
>
> For the Jedi starfighter, which often
> operates independently, its operational range needed to support the
> scope of the individual missions undertaken by the Jedi order.